# Is it natural to say "My promises are absolute"?

Tags: grammar

I just want to make a powerful statement about the powerful commitment towards my promises.

Comment: Any assurances you give somebody about your promises is also a promise. So, there is no way to convince a skeptical person through impassioned statements alone. However, if you provide evidence that you fulfilled a promise of yours even when it was inconvenient to do so, this may convince a reasonable person of your commitment.

Comment: If you're a politician, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your phrase is understandable but not common.

A formal expression is **my word is my bond**.

> old-fashioned or formal
>   If someone's word is their bond, they always
>   keep a promise:
>
> "But listen, you must promise never to tell anyone." "My word is my
>   bond."
>   [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/your-word-is-your-)

**Other possibilities**

I always keep my word/promises.

I say what I mean and I mean what I say.